# How can I trigger a photography strobe from a iPhone LED flash?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, light, basic

I would like to trigger a photography/studio strobe flash based on the flash of an iPhone camera's LED flash. I'm picturing a device that I could attach to the back of the iPhone temporarily when I want the system to work. I would like it to respond in less than 500ms.

Comment: And what kind of signal does it take to trigger this strobe?

Comment: @MattYoung, good question. I plan on using a trigger cable which I believe simply flashes the strobe on a completed circuit.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's what he said, but what is the big strobe expecting? Are we talking TTL, or some other voltage levels? A pulse, or just an edge? As it stands, there isn't enough here to even start to suggest a solution.

Comment: I would even consider a basic slave AC version: http://www.adorama.com/JTS20.html?gclid=CPuTk_G3tbkCFWuCQgodiDYAAw but I think these require a certain range of light to be emitted near by to activate.

Comment: Is the IPhone a single flash or does it use pre-flashes to set up exposure? - this determines the type of optical slave you should use.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about 500 ms.  That would be a very slow shutter speed.  In any case, responding much faster than that is no problem.

Photographic strobes are triggered by a contact closure.  Unfortunately the current and open circuit voltage can vary widely, so it is best to use a relay for the general case.  You could use a transistor, which would trigger faster, if you know something about the strobe you are trying to trigger.

The question then becomes how to trigger a relay from a light flash.  The important characteristic of the trigger flash is that it is a fast pulse event, something that doesn't happen much on otherwise.  I'd probably rig up a photodiode into a transipedance amplifier and look for a pulse.  This can be done by high-pass filtering and thresholding the amplifier output.  When the threshold is detected, turn on the relay for 100 ms or so.  That is much longer than a small relay will take to turn on, and much much longer than the resulting strobe flash.

Comment: you would be absolutely right about the shutter speed if this was being used for photography. I won't actually be taking any pictures with this setup. There is an app that uses the LED flash for another purpose that I would like trigger off of.

Comment: As I understand it *studio strobe flashguns* are usually [triggered optically](http://www.scantips.com/lights/trigger.html) not by contact closure.